# Error while trying to import a function from another js file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import a function called secretPhraseToPublicKey from index.js.

```
import {secretPhraseToPublicKey} from "./index.js";
```

It is giving me this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

I have reviewed information about import and it seems that the way I have written the import should be valid. What else would cause me to have this error?

Comment: 1) how do you export it? 2) are you using node.js?

Comment: `const secretPhraseToPublicKey = require('./index.js');`

Comment: If you are using Node.js then you need to name your other file with the extension .mjs and then import the function like this ‘import {function name} from ‘filenamewithoutextension’;

Answer (score 1):

Three things for that to work:

1. `index.js` must have an export named `secretPhraseToPublicKey`.
2. The `<script>` that does the `import` needs to be included in the HTML with `type="module"`.
3. You need to use a browser that supports ES6 imports (e.g. Firefox, Chrome).

Either 2. or 3. is the reason for the error message you are getting.

Comment: if he is using node.js, points 2 and 3 are not relevant at all

Comment: OP didn't mention node.js in any way, so it's safe to assume he's using a browser.

Comment: I am just using the browser for my code, but I got the module (including index.js) via npm. index.js includes require, which from my reading seems to indicated it uses node. So it looks like I'm using a node module in the browser... is that even possible? I made sure I addressed all 3 points above and its still not working.

Comment: Please show all relevant parts of all files involved.